# Streaming from speaker using bluetooth

Tags: arch-linux, pulseaudio, bluetooth, streaming, manjaro

I'm on Manjaro xfce latest update 64 bit, I have [Jbl charge 2](http://www.jbl.com/bluetooth-portables/JBL+CHARGE+II.html?dwvar_JBL%20CHARGE%20II_color=Black), I was able to connect to it and trust it through bluetooth. The thing I don't know how to stream my laptop's audio through it. I played around with PulseAudio volume control, changed settings and stuff, got nothing. So how to do it?

seems like a blueman problem, I think I see this error

```
Bluetooth device added successfully but failed to connect
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by installing pulseaudio-bluetooth, I'm still configuring it for the audio to work properly but this is a starting point

Comment: Any update after install pulseaudio-bluetooth? How does one tell pulseaudio to play on bluetooth device?

Comment: @GabrielZiegler I'm no longer on Mangaro, I'm on ubuntu 16.04, but I still have the speaker if you want me test it on ubuntu and see if everything is working, because I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: I just it solved, I can post the step-by-step to my solution on getting everything done later, thanks for the will to help tho

Comment: @GabrielZiegler If you post your answer, I'll accept and upvote it

Answer (score 0):

I have connected my Bose Color II on my Arch Linux following a few steps from the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth):

1. Install the dependencies.

```
pacman -Syu bluez bluez-utils
```

2. Start the bluetooth service(Alternatively enable it to skip this step in the next times).

```
systemctl start bluetooth.service
```

3. Run the Bluetooth service shell.

```
bluetoothctl
```

4. An example session taken from the [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth#Pairing):

```
# bluetoothctl 
[NEW] Controller 00:10:20:30:40:50 pi [default]
[bluetooth]# agent KeyboardOnly 
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# default-agent 
Default agent request successful
[bluetooth]# power on
Changing power on succeeded
[CHG] Controller 00:10:20:30:40:50 Powered: yes
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 00:10:20:30:40:50 Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device 00:12:34:56:78:90 myLino
[CHG] Device 00:12:34:56:78:90 LegacyPairing: yes
[bluetooth]# pair 00:12:34:56:78:90
Attempting to pair with 00:12:34:56:78:90
[CHG] Device 00:12:34:56:78:90 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 00:12:34:56:78:90 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 00:12:34:56:78:90 Connected: yes
Request PIN code
[agent] Enter PIN code: 1234
[CHG] Device 00:12:34:56:78:90 Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[CHG] Device 00:12:34:56:78:90 Connected: no
[bluetooth]# connect 00:12:34:56:78:90
Attempting to connect to 00:12:34:56:78:90
[CHG] Device 00:12:34:56:78:90 Connected: yes
Connection successful
```

After pairing your audio streaming device, I suggest you to use [pavucontrol](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/pavucontrol/) to choose the Bluetooth device as the output device.